# Loop an Loop in an xml file?

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

i hava an xml file like this:

```
<name>
    <entry>
        <date>2012-03-18 13:53:23</date>
        <ID>1</ID>
        <category>questions</category>
        <question>who are you?</question>
    <answers>
        <answer text='a man' id='1'/>
        <answer text='a woman' id='2'/>
        <answer text='an animal' id='3'/>
        <answer text='an alien' id='4'/>
    </answers>
        <author>Gorge</author>
    </entry>
</name>
```

And i'm trying to loop all fields, but when i get to the answer point it dosent loop all the answers

any tips how i can manage that?

I'm using:

```
foreach($xml->entry as $entry){
echo "<p>";
echo "<strong>Author:</strong> ".$entry->author."<br/>";
echo "</p>";
}
```

For getting the result.

Thanx in advance
Patrik

Comment: How are you looping the fields? In code? With XSLT?

Comment: Is there a `foreach($entry->answers->answer as $answer)` somewhere in your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you're using SimpleXML. You probably want to do something along these lines:

```
foreach($xml->entry as $entry){
  //iterating through your entry-elements
  echo $entry->question . '<br />';

  foreach($entry->answers->answer as $answer) {
    //iterating through the anwers of the entry-element
    echo $answer['text'] . '<br />';
  }
}
```

Output:

> who are you?
>
> - a man
> - a woman
> - an animal
> - an alien

http://codepad.org/Nfbo4l59

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using DOMDocument() class.

```
    <?php
    $xml="<name>
        <entry>
            <date>2012-03-18 13:53:23</date>
            <ID>1</ID>
            <category>questions</category>
            <question>who are you?</question>
        <answers>
            <answer text='a man' id='1'/>
            <answer text='a woman' id='2'/>
            <answer text='an animal' id='3'/>
            <answer text='an alien' id='4'/>
        </answers>
            <author>Gorge</author>
        </entry>
    </name>
    ";
    $dom=new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadXML($xml);

    foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('entry') as $tagentry)
    {
        foreach($tagentry->getElementsByTagName('answers') as $taganswers)
        {
            foreach($taganswers->getElementsByTagName('answer') as $taganswer)
            {
                $taganswer_array[]=$taganswer->getAttribute('text');
            }
        }
    }

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($taganswer_array);
    echo "</pre>";
    ?>
```

Output::

```
Array(

   [0] => a man  

   [1] => a woman 

   [2] => an animal 

   [3] => an alien
```

)